# How to change the project name in CakePhp 3.x

Tags: .htaccess, routes, cakephp-3.0

I have this project called '**site01**'.

It is published as: '**www.example.com/site01**'. The pages are like this '**www.example.com/site01/page/1**'.

I'm able to route the url to '**www.example.com/site01/1**', but can I change the url to '**www.example.com/s/1**' through the routes configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially I think that you have to use **.htaccess** way, because the issue is related to the outside of the **CakePHP** folder.

You can create a new file named .htaccess in the upper folder and write the instruction witch redirect `/site01/` to `/s/`.

sample code for rewrite url:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^site01.*$ /s/ [R=301,L]
```